# How efficient are coincidence counting techniques?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement, experimental-technology

Obviously there is a limitation as to how well experimental configurations that depend on coincidence counting can efficiently remove the noise present at any given experiment. This leads me to wondering, how efficient are modern day coincidence counting techniques? A percentage of noise removed, signal to noise ratio, an evidenced estimation, or something of the like would suffice.

Comment: IMO this measure  depends drastically on the experiment's apparatus and design and is one of the important numbers to be included in the results publication usually within the error bars on the results, not separately . No general formula could exist.

Comment: I agree with @annav that this varies widely by experiment. Additionally: most modern coincidence counting of entangled photons does not involve much noise as you might conventionally define it. The issues are usually around relative arrival times (defining the coincidence time window) and detector efficiency and other attributes. You can see this in an older paper (2003), see Fig. 2 (page 15) https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0303018 You might check out https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.03189.pdf as this experiment features "high-efficiency, low-noise, single-photon detectors" and was performed in 2016.